# Can we add rpm and deb packages in a single linux distro?

Tags: rpm, dpkg

Can we add RPM and dpkg package management onto a single linux os while creating a linux distro using LFS?

Comment: Technically, yes, it's possible. I can't see a valid reason to do it, though. It's a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I think the two package systems will not be interoperable. That means when you will install a `rmp` package which has a dependency installed from a `deb` package, the dependency will not be recognized as installed.